# helper function to determine if html text is wrapped with a certain tag

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, dom

I have this code that I've made to parse a string of HTML and tell me if it is all enclosed within a specified tag:

```
const textIsWrappedWithTag = (text, tag) => {
  const tempDocument = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, "text/xml");
  if (tempDocument.getElementsByTagName("parsererror").length) {
    return false;
  }
  if (tempDocument.children.length === 1 && tempDocument.children[0].tagName.toLowerCase() === tag.toLowerCase()) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};
```

My test cases do what I want them to do:

```
const yes = '<p><div><span>one</span></div><div><p>two</p></div></p>';
const no = '<p>one</p><p>two</p><p>three</p>';
const no2 = '<div><p>one</p><p>two</p><p>three</p></div>';


textIsWrappedWithTag(yes, 'p');
> true
textIsWrappedWithTag(no, 'p');
> false
textIsWrappedWithTag(no2, 'p');
> false
```

I played around with this in the console to develop it, but I'm not super famliar with `DOMParser` and `parsererror`, so I want to be sure that I'm not overlooking something

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. `textIsWrappedWithTag(yes, 'p');` actually returns `false` instead of `true`...

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ ah sorry, I left out a `.length` check. Fixed that and now it returns `true`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks good and concise.

Your test cases cover almost every branch of the code, which is also good.

You can improve the variable names:

- The `temp` in `tempDocument` is not necessary. Therefore the variable name should better be `document`, or if that is too long, `doc`. Be careful though when abbreviating variable names, and don't make them ambiguous.
- The `no` test case should rather be called `parsererror`. I had to run the code to see that it really tests this branch of the code. By improving the name of the variable, you make this more obvious.

There is a test case missing for a tag name other than `p`.

```
if (doc.children.length === 1 && doc.children[0].tagName.toLowerCase() === tag.toLowerCase()) {
  return true;
}
return false;
```

If you want, you can write this code a bit shorter:

```
return doc.children.length === 1
    && doc.children[0].tagName.toLowerCase() === tag.toLowerCase();
```

Your current code is a bit longer, but it allows you to set a breakpoint on the `return true` statement, which may be useful when debugging the code. But since you already have automated tests running, you will probably not need to set a breakpoint there. Your choice. Many programmers prefer the shorter form, but the longer form is not bad per se.

The expression `doc.children.length === 1` is always true. This is because you are parsing the text using the `text/xml` type, and the XML standard requires exactly 1 root element. Everything else will end up in the parsererror branch. To verify this, you should add a test case for an empty string. And a test case for an XML comment, such as `<!-- comment -->`.

When I first read the function name `textIsWrappedWithTag`, I didn't know exactly what to expect from that function. My first thought was that `textIsWrappedWithTag('<div><p>text</p></div>', 'p')` would return true, since there is some text that is enclosed in a `p` tag. You could try to find a better name for that function, maybe `topLevelElementIs`.

By the way, the DOM API talks about *elements*, while the HTML standard calls them *tags*. If you want your function to feel like it belongs to the DOM API, you should call it `textIsWrappedWithElement` instead.